# Database design using SQL Server 2005,

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a `user` table with `userid (pk), password, usertype`.

I have another table `student` with `stdid (pk), stdname, stdaddress`.

I have a third table `faculty` with `facid (pk), facname, facaddress`.

What I want to do is populate the `user` table with the pk from either `student` table or `faculty` table.

How do I implement this in SQL Server 2005.

Can someone help me?

**Edited Below**

In my database, the student and faculty table are already implemented as part of another module.  I need to implement the authentication part over LAN to be able to be accessed from anywhere, so I can not restructure that part.  So I am using the user table with userid (username) and password in that table.

The userid is either stdid or facid and also the pk of the user table.

Comment: How are the three tables related? You have not mentioned any foreign keys.

Comment: just an observation but please don't put prefixes on columns like fac and std

Comment: But don't ever use ID either. It can cause issues with reporting and mistatekes in joins and is not a good practice art all. Spell out faculty or student.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is a bad design. You do not want to use one or the other other PK as the PK in a table. This cannot every work. What happens when you try to insert student 10 (who is Joe Jones) but faculty 10 (Mary Smith) is already in the table. Well, the insert would fail becuse of the unique requirement of a PK.

If all studetns and faculty are always users, then userID is the PK and FacultyId and StudentID are the FKs to that table not the reverse.

Comment: All the stdid are prefixed 'S' and all facid are prefixed 'F'.

Comment: So, I should get a userid as pk and get another field to put either the stdid or facid?

Answer (score 0):

insert into user_table (select facid as userid from facultaty_table union select stdid as userid from student_table)

this will leave column password and usertype as null otherwise it pumps up userid_table with all the PKs from the others

Comment: And if stdid and facid come from overlapping domains?

Answer (score 0):

What are the data types of the keys?  Is there a guarantee that they're going to be unique across both the student and faculty tables?

This seems like it's going to be a difficult design to work with over time.  Maybe try moving the central focus from the "person" tables to the user table and assign roles from there?  Something like this:

```
User
------
Id
Password
UserType
(where's the username?)

UserInfo
------
UserID
Name
Address

Role
------
Id
Name

UserRole
------
UserID
RoleID
```

(The `Role` table would have at least two records, one called "Student" and one called "Faculty", but could allow for more roles as well.)

There are a few benefits here:

1. You need only store names and addresses in one place, rather than duplicate the model across different roles.
2. A user can have multiple roles.  For example, a faculty member could take some classes and be a "student" for a while.  A grad student can teach some classes and be a "faculty member" for a while.
3. New roles can be added without having to change the data model.